# Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase command is failing while lowering the Azure SQL DB pricing tier due to key vault soft delete

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault, soft-delete

I'm using an automated powershell script to downgrade the pricing tier of the database backup copy. While supplying the below command the tier downgrade fails. The error, if I understood correctly is referring to key-vault with a key named same as my server name, since there is no such key exists(hence the soft delete can also be not enabled), this command fails.

The command has been set-up when my application was not set-up with key-vault and seems like now it's failing.

**Command used:**

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName <*Back-up DB name*> -ServerName <*SQL server name*> -ResourceGroupName <*Resource Group name*> -Edition Standard -RequestedServiceObjectiveName S0
```

**Error:**

> Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase : 45377: **The provided Key Vault uri**
>   'https://****.vault.azure.net/keys/<*SERVERNAME*>/<*Subscription/some
>   ID*> **is not  valid. Please ensure the key vault has been configured
>   with soft-delete.** (https://aka.ms/sqltdebyoksoftdelete) At line:1
>   char:2
>   +  Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName <*Back-up DB name*> -ServerName <*SQL server name*>...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlDatabase

**Questions :**
1.Why Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase command is referring to a key-vault URI, when not mentioned explicitly ?

2.Is there a option we need to set at the server/DB level to allow this command to read the server/DB name directly rather than searching for a key with server name?

3. Is this anywhere related to Transparent data encryption ?
4. Are we suppose to make any changes to this command if the key-vault comes later than the application/DB/key-vault set-up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was purely related to **TDE(Transparent data encryption)** as I thought of. Since Azure SQL databases were secured by TDE, it was expected that the key-vault should also be enabled with soft delete to recover any deleted keys.
While trying to enable soft-delete, I figured out that the Azure powershell installed on my machine doesn't support soft delete property.

I am able to resolve this issue by following steps :

1. Upgraded powershell :
   [Installation Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950)
2. Login into your azure subscription and run this command

   `$vault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName myvault; $vault.EnableSoftDelete`
3. If the above doesn't work run the below command. This will find the resourceId of the key-vault and then will enable soft-delete  -

`($resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId (Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "YourKeyVaultNameHere").ResourceId).Properties | Add-Member - 
MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "enableSoftDelete" -Value "true"`

`Set-AzureRmResource -resourceid $resource.ResourceId -Properties $resource.Properties`

4. Verify if the key-vault soft-delete is enabled by below command

`Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "YourKeyVaultNameHere"`

Hope this would be helpful for someone facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some personal opinions for you to refer.

First, per my test, the command works fine on my side.

**Note**: In my test environment, it is a sql server and database without any other things, like transparent data encryption.

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName joydatabase -ServerName joydb -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Edition Standard -RequestedServiceObjectiveName S0
```

[image]

> Why Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase command is referring to a key-vault URI, when not mentioned explicitly ?

On my side, I catch the request via fiddler, it is not referring to a key-vault URL, refer to the screenshot.

[image]

> Is there a option we need to set at the server/DB level to allow this command to read the server/DB name directly rather than searching for a key with server name?

On my side, I think we needn't to do so.

> Is this anywhere related to Transparent data encryption ?

I think there is a great possibility that it is related to it. You could create a new sql server and database to have a try. Here is an article about transparent data encryption for azure sql server, you could refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql?view=azuresqldb-current).

> Are we suppose to make any changes to this command if the key-vault comes later than the application/DB/key-vault set-up ?

I think it seems not make any change to this command.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis at your end. But the issue remains the same, somehow in my scenario key-vault is referred. Are you having a keyvault set-up for you application/DB ?

Comment: @swatigupta No, it just a single database, so I suppose the issue may caused by azure keyvault. As the error message mentioned, if you enable soft delete, will it works? May be you could have a try.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a key with the name of DB in key-vault neither I'm sure what that key and secret should be there. Once the key is in place I can try enabling the soft delete. Moreover, it is crucial to understand is why the key vault URL is referred. I doubt there could be some setting in azure portal which redirects any DB names to check the key-vault.

Comment: @swatigupta It makes sense, if you do not have a key, it is hard to explain, including the keyvault url is referred. I recommend you to [contact Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for help.